# Retrieving Enum values from unknown String

Tags: java, enums

I have a moderately-sized Enum in which I want to retrieve values from given a String. For example,

```
GAUL_RAM("gaul_ram.schem", new Location(Bukkit.getWorld(Statics.worldName), 0, 100, 0)),
GAUL_RAM_UPGRADED("gaul_ram_upgraded.schem", new Location(Bukkit.getWorld(Statics.worldName), 0, 100, 0)),  
GREEK_RAM("greek_ram.schem", new Location(Bukkit.getWorld(Statics.worldName), 0, 100, 0)),
GREEK_RAM_UPGRADED("greek_ram_upgraded.schem", new Location(Bukkit.getWorld(Statics.worldName), 0, 100, 0)),
PERSIA_RAM("persia_ram.schem", new Location(Bukkit.getWorld(Statics.worldName), 0, 100, 0)),
PERSIA_RAM_UPGRADED("persia_ram_upgraded.schem", new Location(Bukkit.getWorld(Statics.worldName), 0, 100, 0)),
CARTHAGE_RAM("carthage_ram.schem", new Location(Bukkit.getWorld(Statics.worldName), 0, 100, 0)),
CARTHAGE_RAM_UPGRADED("carthage_ram_upgraded.schem", new Location(Bukkit.getWorld(Statics.worldName), 0, 100, 0));
```

I have the above enum. I may be passed a value such as "persia". What I want to do then is pull the String value from the Persia constant `PERSIA_RAM`, as well as its `Location` object.

However, I do not see a 'clean' way of doing this. Solutions that come to mind are checking the provided String "persia", iterating over all values in the enum via `Object[] possibleValues = enumValue.getDeclaringClass().getEnumConstants().toString().toLowerCase();`, and then using some sort of delimiter on underscores '_' to get the first word in the enum constant.

Again, this isn't a slick solution. Is there a better way to accomplish this task?

Comment: `Arrays.stream(YourEnum.values()).filter( /* match the given string */ ).findAny()` If you [edit] your question and provide the actual code of your enum, I can give you a more accurate solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a `HashMap` of String to enum at the time the class is loaded, so you don't have to do string operations every time you want to look up an enum value.  Below is an example of how I would do this:

```
public class Testing {
    public static final HashMap<String, Enum> map = new HashMap<>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (Enum e : Enum.values()) {
            map.put(e.toString().toLowerCase().split("_")[0], e);
        }

        System.out.println(map.get("persia").getString());
    }

    public enum Enum {
        GAUL_RAM("gaul_ram.schem", new Location(Bukkit.getWorld(Statics.worldName), 0, 100, 0)),
        GAUL_RAM_UPGRADED("gaul_ram_upgraded.schem", new Location(Bukkit.getWorld(Statics.worldName), 0, 100, 0)),  
        GREEK_RAM("greek_ram.schem", new Location(Bukkit.getWorld(Statics.worldName), 0, 100, 0)),
        GREEK_RAM_UPGRADED("greek_ram_upgraded.schem", new Location(Bukkit.getWorld(Statics.worldName), 0, 100, 0)),
        PERSIA_RAM("persia_ram.schem", new Location(Bukkit.getWorld(Statics.worldName), 0, 100, 0)),
        PERSIA_RAM_UPGRADED("persia_ram_upgraded.schem", new Location(Bukkit.getWorld(Statics.worldName), 0, 100, 0)),
        CARTHAGE_RAM("carthage_ram.schem", new Location(Bukkit.getWorld(Statics.worldName), 0, 100, 0)),
        CARTHAGE_RAM_UPGRADED("carthage_ram_upgraded.schem", new Location(Bukkit.getWorld(Statics.worldName), 0, 100, 0));

        private String arg0;
        private Location arg1

        private Enum (String s, Location l) {
            arg0 = s;
            arg1 = l
        }

        public String getString() {
            return arg0;
        }

        public Location getLoc() {
            return arg1;
        }
    }
}
```

This returns:

```
persia_ram_upgraded.schem
```

Note that this does leave some ambiguity between some of your enum values.  For instance, `PERSIA_RAM` and `PERSIA_RAM_UPGRADED` will both correspond to a string of `"persia"`.  I would recommend either some renaming, or rethinking how you want to access your enum values.